# Show HTML content from rich:editor

Tags: richfaces, rich-text-editor

I am using rich:editor feature and also able to get the HTML content when user enters data in the editor.

But the question is : Now I have to display the same HTML content back to user. How would I do that.

i.e if I have entered some bold characters in editor, bean property will contain "<strong>bold</strong>" as string.

But when displaying to user, I should not show him those HTML tags rather show him the data as **bold**.

I did something like : "<span>#{testplannerBean.description}</span>" but it displays along with the HTML tags as in image.

[image: editor with html tags]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use h:outputText like this : <h:outputText value="#{testplannerBean.description}" escape="false"></h:outputText>

which escapes the content sensitive to HTML

Answer (score 0):

use tinymce (google it), that would take care of that problem.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to display Html content to readable content, you should use the rich editor's property `richEditorControl1.HtmlText`. HtmlText property will get & set the rich editor's content.